# Rails saving value from dynamic dropdown of foreign model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, nested-attributes

I have two models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cows
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cows
end

class Cow < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
end
```

Every location has an id and a name. A cow consists of an id, two strings and two dates and it also includes a location_id.

In my cow view I have a dropdown of every location. It gets updated automatically whenever I create, edit or delete a location. When I choose a location from the dropdown, the cow index changes based on the fitting location_id in cows.

Cows index.html.erb:

```
<!-- Dropdown Button -->
<a class='dropdown-button' href='#' data-activates='dropdown_locations'>
<i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ort auswählen</a>

<!-- Dropdown Content -->
<ul id='dropdown_locations' class='dropdown-content'>
  <% @locations_all.each do |loc| %>
    <li><%= link_to loc.name, cows_path(location: loc.id) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The cows index page is a page for showing the content and adding new values at the same time. As I mentioned, the index changes based on the selected location. But it only works if I populate the cow table manually in a database editor since the selected location from the dropdown won't be saved to cows.

Here's the form for creating new cows in cows index.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for Cow.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :ohrmarke, as: :string, input_html: { maxlength: 5 } %>
    <%= f.input :stallnummer, as: :string, input_html: { maxlength: 3 } %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :location_id, value: @location_id %>

    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Zuordnung speichern</button>
<% end %>
```

I use a hidden_field for the location_id and the value should be the location_id of the selected location from the dropbox.

But for some reason creating new cows just does not work. Here's my cow controller (shortened):

```
def index
  @locations_all = Location.all
  if (params[:location] && cows = Cow.where(location_id: params[:location]))
    @cows = cows
    @location = Location.where(id: params[:location])
  else
    @cows = Cow.all
  end
end

def new
  @cow = Cow.new
end

def create
  @cow = Cow.new(cow_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @cow.save
      # format.html blabla... the usual stuff
    end
  end
end

private
  def set_cow
    @cow = Cow.find(params[:id])
  end

  def cow_params
    params.require(:cow).permit(:ohrmarke, :hin, :weg, :stallnummer, location_attributes: [:location_id])
  end
end
```

I think that either my hidden_field or the create controller is not working. But I don't know what I did wrong. At least changing the index based on the selected location works. Thanks for any help in advance.

---

**Edit**: I solved it with your help and on my own, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some suggestions I changed the code and set the location_id. Now everything works fine. Here's the new code:

Cow controller:

```
def index
  @locations_all = Location.all
  if (params[:location] && cows = Cow.where(location_id: params[:location]))
    @cows = cows
    @location_id = params[:location] # used for the form
    @location = Location.find(@location_id) # used for ex. showing the name
  else
    @cows = Cow.all
  end
end

def cow_params
  params.require(:cow).permit(:ohrmarke, :hin, :weg, :stallnummer, :location_id)
end
```

Form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :location_id, value: @location_id %>
```

I also changed the models accordingly (moved nested_attributes to Cow).

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you have said that `Location accepts_nested_attributes_for for :cows`, but your form and your controller are set up as `Cow accepts_nested_attributes_for :location.`  I think if you change your model to be

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :cows

end

class Cow < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

you should get somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but nothing changes. While the index still works, my new values won't be saved with the selected location(id). I'm not getting any error so it's hard to figure out what's wrong in my code.

Comment: That is because you never actually pass a location in.  You wrote `value: @location_id` but in the controller action you never set @location_id.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're setting location

```
def cow_params
  params.require(:cow).permit(:ohrmarke, :hin, :weg, :stallnummer, location_attributes: [:location_id])
end
```

Should be

```
def cow_params
  params.require(:cow).permit(:ohrmarke, :hin, :weg, :stallnummer, :location_id)
end
```

The location doesn't have a `location_id`.  I think you just want to set that on the cow.